# How to install Artic Wolf Agent on Android?

Tags: applications, installation

I would like to install Artic Wolf Agent on Zebra VC8300 and MC930B mobile computers that use Android 11.

[Here](https://docs.arcticwolf.com/agent/installing_linux.html) are the instructions I have and I'm trying to figure out which ones to follow for that build.

> 4. Run the appropriate command, based on your operating system and preferred package manager:
>
>    - Ubuntu (using APT):
>
>      ```
>      sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive AWN_CUSTOMER_JSON=/tmp/customer.json apt install /tmp/arcticwolfagent_<version>.deb
>      ```
>    - CentOS, Red Hat, or Amazon Linux:
>
>      - YUM (preferred):
>
>        ```
>        sudo AWN_CUSTOMER_JSON=/tmp/customer.json yum install arcticwolfagent_<version>.rpm
>        ```
>      - Zypper:
>
>        ```
>        sudo AWN_CUSTOMER_JSON=/tmp/customer.json zypper install --allow-unsigned-rpm arcticwolfagent_<version>.rpm
>        ```
>      - DNF:
>
>        ```
>        sudo AWN_CUSTOMER_JSON=/tmp/customer.json dnf install arcticwolfagent_<version>.rpm
>        ```
>
> Notes:
>
> - You must place `customer.json` in the `/tmp` folder.
> - Use an absolute path to `customer.json` and verify that it is correct. If any errors occur pertaining to the `customer.json` file, see Arctic Wolf Agent Troubleshooting.
> - You can install Agent with any package manager on CentOS, Red Hat, or Amazon Linux, but only YUM has been tested.
> - Agent only performs automated tests with YUM, DNF, and Zypper.

Comment: Sorry but this Stackexchange is a question and answer portal but your post misses the question. Please edit your question and describe in your words what you are doing (e.g. what commands you use) and what is going wrong. BTW. Your post contains instructions for installing Wolf Agent on Linux, but Android is not a regular Linux system. So this can only fail.